# Java compiler linux

Tags: java

I was on windows and my compiler code was

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\javac.exe" -classpath deps/log4j-1.2.15.jar;deps/jython.jar;deps/xstream.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/poi.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar -d bin src\server\event\*.java src\server\model\items\*.java    src\server\model\minigames\*.java src\server\model\npcs\*.java src\server\model\objects\*.java src\server\model\players\*.java src\server\model\players\skills\*.java src\server\model\players\packets\*.java src\server\model\shops\*.java src\server\net\*.java src\server\task\*.java src\server\util\*.java src\server\world\*.java src\server\util\log\*.java src\server\*.java src\server\world\map\*.java
pause
```

Now when I moved to linux, it doesn't work.
I've tried to change it to .sh file and edited like this

```
javac -classpath deps/log4j-1.2.15.jar:deps/jython.jar:deps/xstream.jar:deps/mina.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/poi.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar -d bin src/server/event/*.java src/server/model/items/*.java src/server/model/minigames/*.java src/server/model/npcs/*.java src/server/model/objects/*.java src/server/model/players/*.java src/server/model/players/skills/*.java src/server/model/players/packets/*.java src/server/model/shops/*.java src/server/net/*.java src/server/task/*.java src/server/util/*.java src/server/world/*.java src/server/util/log/*.java src/server/*.java src/server/world/map/*.java
```

Basically I changed ; to :, \ to /
After running sh compile.sh in shell, I get error.

```
javac: invalid flag: src/server/world/map/*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
: not found 2: compile.sh:
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to compile java files in only 1 folder first, maybe you have to double quote the sources or the line is too long... 
is the java version the same on the 2 environments?

Comment: When I try to compile in 1 folder, it gives me basically the same error, just different  invalid flag.. Yes java versions are the same

Comment: what is javac -version on linux? also you can try -g or -verbose switch to get more info...
is there a space in the folder path of the folder where you are executing the command? that could cause issues sometimes...

Comment: Actually I just checked, and version is 1.7.0_21 but does it make any difference? When I try javac -g or javac -verbose in shell it gives me no source error, when I add it to my compiler.sh nothing changes. And ther is no spaces in folder names.. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: You should care about that in general! but based on the Java7 javac documentation, it shouldn't make any difference, because it has the same arguments

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little research it seems this problem might be caused by incorrect line endings in your .sh file. Have you tried completely retyping it in vi, emacs, vim, or something like that?

Comment: I just tried leafpad and gedit, but nothing changed.. I am thinking to  completely reinstall jdk, maybe something could be wrong with paths or something like that, but I doubt it..

Comment: And yes reinstalling jdk didn't helped